How do I change the Froala Editors BOLD tag?
I'm using the Froala Editor v4 and have a request to change what happens when the bold button is clicked.  The default is to use the <strong> tag.  The client wants the <b> tag used instead.  I'm not finding where I can change this or if it's even possible.
